# How can i extract values except double quotes in lua

Tags: regex, string, lua, openwrt, luci

this is a string

```
"'"id"':001 (it is visualized "id":001)
```

I want to capture only the values in lua.
if there is not double quotes, i can extract values only.
(use something:`gmatch((%a+)%sd:%s(%d+))`)

Is there anyone who solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use a `"(%w+)"%s*:%s*(%d+)` pattern:

```
local example = [[ "id":001 "id2":002 ]]
for i,y in example:gmatch([["(%w+)"%s*:%s*(%d+)]]) do
  print(i, y)
end
```

See the [Lua demo](https://ideone.com/owJK26), output:

```
id  001
id2 002
```

The `"(%w+)"%s*:%s*(%d+)` pattern matches

- `"` - a double quote
- `(%w+)` - Group 1: one or more alphanumeric chars (use `[%w_]+` to also match `_`)
- `"` - a `"`
- `%s*:%s*` - a colon enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `(%d+)` - Group 2: one or more digits

Comment: I have one more question. I want to extract the values in each. Is there something to do that i can?

Comment: @EuDdeumPark If you have any doubts, please post a link to the Lua fiddle if you still have trouble with it. I actually do not understand what you meant by "extract the values in each". `string.gmatch` extracts all matches. If you do need a specific match, use `string.match` with a pattern like `[["id"%s*:%s*(%d+)]]`.

Comment: @Stribizew I used for loop, and I solved my newest problem. Thank you.

Comment: @EuDdeumPark: Ok, glad it worked for you. Please also consider upvoting if my answer proved helpful to you (see [How to upvote on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow)).